# Solace JNDI/JMS Syntax for C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, jms, solace

A vendor is using Solace to send messages. I have obtained a SubscriptionId using web service call, that I supposed to be submitted to the Solace server.

Using the documentation and sample code at dev.solace.com, I have been able to connect a session. However, I am lost as to how to go to the next step which is to subscribe to what I believe is a queue using a connection factory, jndi factory an jms destination name.

The sample shows this:

```
Session.Connect(ContextFactory.Instance.CreateQueue(Topic), true);
```

But from what I can tell, that won't work as the vendor wants jndi/jms, and the Solace documentation has no .NET code for jndi/jms, which leaves me guessing.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the JMS API instead of the .NET API in order to perform JMS.
The .NET API does not do JMS.

Note that you can send/receive messages using the .NET API that's inter-operable with the JMS API.

However, since you have a hard requirement to use JMS, your only option is to use the JMS API.

Answer (score 0):

As It turns out, the jndi/jms information delivered by the host for configuration  was unneeded. What was necessary was to connect to the queue and receive the messages.